# leaflet : how to get the popup content on marker click?

Tags: leaflet

i cannot find the method to get the popup content on marker click?

http://jsfiddle.net/zpd6mjnb/

```
> //An extract of address points from the LINZ bulk extract:
> http://www.linz.govt.nz/survey-titles/landonline-data/landonline-bde
> //Should be this data set:
> http://data.linz.govt.nz/#/layer/779-nz-street-address-electoral/ var
> addressPoints = [ [-37.793167, 175.211862,"the one"], [-37.8210922667,
> 175.2209316333, "2"], [-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "3"], [-37.8210881833, 175.2215004833, "3A"], [-37.8211946833,
> 175.2213655333, "1"], [-37.8209458667, 175.2214051333, "5"], [-37.8208292333, 175.2214374833, "7"], [-37.8325816, 175.2238798667,
> "537"], [-37.8315855167, 175.2279767, "454"], [-37.8096336833,
> 175.2223743833, "176"], [-37.80970685, 175.2221815833, "178"], [-37.8102146667, 175.2211562833, "190"], [-37.8088037167, 175.2242227,
> "156"], [-37.8112330167, 175.2193425667, "210"], [-37.8116368667,
> 175.2193005167, "212"], [-37.80812645, 175.2255449333, "146"], [-37.8080231333, 175.2286383167, "125"], [-37.8089538667,
> 175.2222222333, "174"], [-37.8080905833, 175.2275400667, "129"], [-37.808811, 175.2227592833, "172"], [-37.80832975, 175.2276898167,
> "131"], [-37.8089395333, 175.2281710333, "133"], [-37.8093421,
> 175.2274883167, "135"], [-37.8084820833, 175.22601925, "137"], [-37.80881015, 175.22622865, "139"], [-37.8090947667, 175.2263585667,
> "141"], [-37.8092962333, 175.2244872333, "147"], [-37.8091016667,
> 175.2249140167, "145"], [-37.8088785167, 175.2253611667, "143"], [-37.80825965, 175.22530115, "148"], [-37.80995685, 175.2238554333,
> "153"], [-37.80975435, 175.2238417833, "151"], [-37.80950755,
> 175.2237912, "149"], [-37.8092772667, 175.2231980833, "170"], [-37.8082753833, 175.20672975, "4"], [-37.8078434833, 175.211822,
> "56"], [-37.8083775667, 175.2090812333, "30B"], [-37.8084588,
> 175.2058838167, "174"], [-37.8088788333, 175.2062702833, "175"], [-37.8091632833, 175.20514875, "182A"], [-37.8094891167, 175.20384695,
> "202"], [-37.8156715667, 175.2034881667, "277"], [-37.8109189333,
> 175.2024631, "220"], [-37.8108164333, 175.2039622, "219"], [-37.8125773667, 175.2026079667, "238"], [-37.8125799333, 175.2032824,
> "241A"], [-37.8125869, 175.2037423833, "241C"], [-37.8140266833,
> 175.2025706, "256"], [-37.80932, 175.2051094333, "182B"], [-37.8098799667, 175.2040444167, "197"], [-37.8094298833,
> 175.20561245, "189"], [-37.8172409333, 175.2035291167, "287"], [-37.8232166667, 175.22452865, "2028"], [-37.8225024333,
> 175.2249944667, "2022"], [-37.82334135, 175.2244748667, "2030"], [-37.8229725333, 175.2246809333, "2026"], [-37.8224034667,
> 175.22507345, "2020"], [-37.8227806, 175.2248285833, "2024"], [-37.8178801, 175.2181871667, "6"], [-37.81811315, 175.2180543667,
> "4"], [-37.8181739833, 175.21851995, "1"], [-37.81797515, 175.2186312,
> "3"], [-37.8181787, 175.2176995, "2A"], [-37.8183385333, 175.21812895,
> "2"], [-37.8293053167, 175.2105357833, "31"], [-37.8309444333,
> 175.21208735, "16"], [-37.8306726667, 175.2115020833, "19"], [-37.8300903, 175.2120791, "26"], [-37.8289416167, 175.2113778333,
> "33"], [-37.8274969167, 175.2113355167, "53"], [-37.8199192667,
> 175.2173622833, "5A"], [-37.8200392833, 175.2174100167, "3"], [-37.8196328, 175.2167642, "18"], [-37.81752585, 175.2155467667,
> "22C"], [-37.81766615, 175.2153714167, "22B"], [-37.8179022667,
> 175.2151616833, "22A"], [-37.8191980333, 175.21664245, "20A"], [-37.81799325, 175.21565925, "20C"], [-37.8187486333, 175.2165228667,
> "20B"], [-37.81964875, 175.2172874167, "7"], [-37.81925545,
> 175.2171617, "11"], [-37.8190491667, 175.2170928333, "13"], [-37.8194515667, 175.2172147167, "9"], [-37.81981045, 175.21733245,
> "5B"], [-37.81876595, 175.2172445167, "15B"], [-37.8185999167,
> 175.2172441, "17A"], [-37.81816745, 175.21725905, "21B"], [-37.8182157167, 175.2164626333, "24"], [-37.8180109667,
> 175.2173984167, "23A"], [-37.8179918, 175.217159, "23B"], [-37.8188473167, 175.2170330333, "15"], [-37.8186481333,
> 175.2169800667, "17"], [-37.8184132, 175.2169327333, "19"], [-37.8202288333, 175.2174746333, "1"], [-37.818193, 175.2169955667,
> "21"], [-37.8178000833, 175.21733275, "25"], [-37.8176839,
> 175.2168488333, "26"], [-37.8198172, 175.2204960667, "5"], [-37.819986, 175.22049635, "3"], [-37.8197666, 175.2200825, "4"],
> [-37.8193835833, 175.2191669667, "10"], [-37.8193426333,
> 175.2198626667, "11"], [-37.8192171667, 175.2191711, "12"], [-37.8192621333, 175.2196364167, "13"], [-37.8195289667,
> 175.2193943167, "8"], [-37.81946, 175.2201499167, "9"], [-37.8196037833, 175.219674, "6"], [-37.8194712, 175.2204032, "7A"],
> [-37.8196381, 175.2203709333, "7"], [-37.8200137667, 175.2201364333,
> "2"], [-37.8191725167, 175.2193772833, "14"], [-37.8214417333,
> 175.2256822167, "4"], [-37.8210291, 175.2259429667, "8"], [-37.8212328333, 175.2258132, "6"], [-37.8216819833, 175.2253209,
> "3"], [-37.8334697167, 175.2038651667, "326"], [-37.8322603667,
> 175.2028621167, "317"], [-37.8322013667, 175.2046802667, "1/341"], [-37.8320576167, 175.2165535833, "435"], [-37.8319540333,
> 175.20506915, "2/341"], [-37.8316975667, 175.2053442333, "3/341"], [-37.8328229833, 175.2062598, "346"], [-37.83161565, 175.2074915,
> "355"], [-37.83219305, 175.20629425, "347"], [-37.8328549,
> 175.2080619667, "362"], [-37.8321289667, 175.2084019333, "367"], [-37.8322225167, 175.2120427667, "397"], [-37.8321649, 175.21119325,
> "393"], [-37.8321458833, 175.2131246333, "407"], [-37.8327043833,
> 175.21377405, "416"], [-37.8321267167, 175.2144058167, "417"], [-37.83212555, 175.2096521333, "373"], [-37.8331028667, 175.20928495,
> "366"], [-37.82866875, 175.22177625, "563"], [-37.8295602,
> 175.21924335, "582"], [-37.8304707833, 175.2182986167, "590"], [-37.83086, 175.2180687667, "592"], [-37.8328604833, 175.2172892167,
> "618"], [-37.8342575667, 175.2168357833, "638"], [-37.8239713,
> 175.2245693667, "504"], [-37.8365260167, 175.2170911, "673"], [-37.8233928833, 175.2249669167, "492"], [-37.8248650167,
> 175.2246300833, "509"], [-37.8191798333, 175.2265331667, "435"], [-37.8143243333, 175.2310940167, "368"], [-37.81459255, 175.2320046,
> "363"], [-37.81127515, 175.2356499167, "311"], [-37.8126359667,
> 175.2340855167, "333"], [-37.8096158333, 175.2375218167, "293"], [-37.8315868667, 175.2177722833, "604"], [-37.8160177667,
> 175.2299268333, "391"], [-37.8204715667, 175.2265481833, "456"], [-37.8206352, 175.2265670333, "458"], [-37.8208412667, 175.2265323333,
> "460"], [-37.8210184333, 175.22648325, "462"], [-37.8212643833,
> 175.2270422167, "465"], [-37.82119945, 175.2264274333, "464"], [-37.82136485, 175.2263145667, "466"], [-37.8215261, 175.22684075,
> "467"], [-37.8215301833, 175.2262078, "468"], [-37.8217701667,
> 175.2266360167, "1/471"], [-37.8218376833, 175.22686725, "2/471"], [-37.8217084667, 175.2260839667, "472"], [-37.8219782333,
> 175.2265028333, "475"], [-37.8218988833, 175.2259723, "476"], [-37.8223939333, 175.2262447, "479"], [-37.8223048667, 175.2256582833,
> "480"], [-37.8226657, 175.2261230833, "481"], [-37.8224199,
> 175.2255487833, "482"], [-37.8229134167, 175.2259527833, "485"], [-37.8226937833, 175.2253693167, "486"], [-37.8231509667,
> 175.2258170333, "487"], [-37.82295265, 175.2252571167, "488"], [-37.8233779, 175.2256743833, "489"], [-37.8232052667, 175.2251109333,
> "490"], [-37.8236200333, 175.22553395, "493"], [-37.82385775,
> 175.2253390833, "495"], [-37.8203220167, 175.22650925, "454"], [-37.8179795333, 175.2262826, "428"], [-37.81038215, 175.2365298167,
> "303"], [-37.8161746667, 175.2297239833, "393"], [-37.8083635333,
> 175.233955, "294"], [-37.82029495, 175.2214968167, "39"], [-37.8204754333, 175.2247793333, "12B"], [-37.8205440833,
> 175.22344905, "23"], [-37.8195974333, 175.2254019333, "2"], [-37.8210801, 175.2237748667, "20A"], [-37.8209057333, 175.22389775,
> "18"], [-37.8208016833, 175.2221582833, "32"], [-37.8209372667,
> 175.2236919, "20"], [-37.8210586833, 175.22351925, "22B"], [-37.82092905, 175.2234855333, "22"], [-37.8208587333, 175.2231887667,
> "24"], [-37.8210241167, 175.2230882, "24B"], [-37.8208547833,
> 175.2229410667, "26"], [-37.8209917, 175.2228447667, "26B"], [-37.82097645, 175.2227176167, "28B"], [-37.8208099167,
> 175.2226765167, "28"], [-37.8207666833, 175.2224338833, "30"], [-37.8209508833, 175.2222094167, "32B"], [-37.82076515,
> 175.2219195167, "34A"], [-37.8207399667, 175.2218131667, "34B"], [-37.8203075833, 175.2240482833, "19"], [-37.8205368167,
> 175.2237746667, "21"], [-37.8205025833, 175.2231658, "25A"], [-37.820465, 175.2229733667, "27"], [-37.82043535, 175.2227387, "29"],
> [-37.8204582, 175.2225319667, "31"], [-37.82024115, 175.2224347833,
> "31B"], [-37.8203792333, 175.2222631667, "33"], [-37.82034095,
> 175.2219843, "35"], [-37.8201566167, 175.2219446, "35B"], [-37.82030575, 175.2217594333, "37"], [-37.8202966833, 175.2233158167,
> "25"], [-37.8192714167, 175.2253842667, "1"], [-37.81969695,
> 175.22516645, "4"], [-37.8194904667, 175.22468815, "5"], [-37.8198524333, 175.2249096667, "6"], [-37.8200581833, 175.2247122,
> "8"], [-37.8193447, 175.2244639667, "5C"], [-37.8208238,
> 175.2241340167, "16"], [-37.8193183667, 175.22515695, "1A"], [-37.81940575, 175.2249383333, "3"], [-37.8211855167, 175.2242545333,
> "18A"], [-37.8207094833, 175.22430275, "14"], [-37.82027725,
> 175.22488135, "10A"], [-37.8202305833, 175.2245652667, "10"], [-37.8205049667, 175.2244201333, "12"], [-37.8196320333, 175.2255586,
> "22"], [-37.8209711, 175.2250444667, "8"], [-37.82120665,
> 175.2252942833, "5"], [-37.8210184, 175.2254290333, "7"], [-37.8213430333, 175.2252086167, "3"], [-37.8207887833,
> 175.2251555667, "10"], [-37.82060805, 175.2257042333, "13"], [-37.8208330333, 175.22553905, "9"], [-37.8216988833, 175.2249665667,
> "1"], [-37.8215665833, 175.2246573333, "2"], [-37.8213729,
> 175.2247789333, "4"], [-37.8211700667, 175.2249324333, "6"], [-37.8205967667, 175.2252867, "12"], [-37.8204008833, 175.2254234667,
> "14"], [-37.82043265, 175.22582195, "15"], [-37.8202037333,
> 175.2255415833, "16"], [-37.8200154333, 175.2256547667, "18"], [-37.8197443167, 175.2256164833, "20"], [-37.8202814333, 175.22590955,
> "17"], [-37.8202967667, 175.21462555, "98"], [-37.82204485,
> 175.21819735, "61B"], [-37.8224241, 175.2179326667, "61C"], [-37.8215043167, 175.2227943833, "24"], [-37.8219082, 175.2255408167,
> "8"], [-37.8216963, 175.2240856667, "14"], [-37.8213418333,
> 175.2188135667, "55"], [-37.8204966333, 175.2183406333, "54A"], [-37.8221799833, 175.21122085, "139"], [-37.8217387, 175.22431625,
> "12"], [-37.8218650167, 175.2149734167, "107"], [-37.8214083333,
> 175.2220152667, "30"], [-37.8213738333, 175.2217301, "32"], [-37.8221598167, 175.2247839333, "9"], [-37.8216356, 175.2235610667,
> "18"], [-37.8212188167, 175.2221387333, "30B"], [-37.8200466667,
> 175.2166111, "84A"], [-37.8216679333, 175.2238393333, "16"], [-37.8211582833, 175.22031685, "34"], [-37.8221918667, 175.2250378333,
> "7"], [-37.8187410167, 175.2067290167, "170C"], [-37.8206532,
> 175.2170745667, "81"], [-37.8212348667, 175.2181024167, "67"], [-37.8213057667, 175.2185351167, "57"], [-37.8214571, 175.2145877333,
> "110"], [-37.82207085, 175.2136727167, "121"], [-37.82190125,
> 175.2123493, "130"], [-37.8207519667, 175.2102467333, "150"], [-37.8212159, 175.2096407, "159"], [-37.8208313833, 175.2067756,
> "172"], [-37.8214413333, 175.2222779833, "28"], [-37.8206921333,
> 175.2182549, "54"], [-37.82043975, 175.2181215, "56"], [-37.8218791, 175.2252452167, "10"], [-37.82029435, 175.2169818, "84"], [-37.8215885167, 175.22308725, "22"], [-37.8215897333, 175.2233113167,
> "20"], [-37.82167455, 175.2183345, "61A"], [-37.8217164667,
> 175.2179857333, "63"], [-37.82147385, 175.22253565, "26"], [-37.8206765333, 175.2160304333, "86"], [-37.8188941, 175.2069437,
> "170A"], [-37.8188068333, 175.2068104833, "170B"], [-37.8193742667,
> 175.2085580333, "170"], [-37.8214388167, 175.2200072, "45"], [-37.8209547167, 175.2157149167, "92"], [-37.82088565, 175.2164849333,
> "85"], [-37.82136235, 175.2159546667, "97"], [-37.8219607333,
> 175.2232987, "19"], [-37.8210501, 175.2179753833, "69"], [-37.8212466667, 175.2222175833, "28A"], [-37.8213836167,
> 175.22300555, "22A"], [-37.821339, 175.2227439167, "24A"], [-37.8208144333, 175.2173117167, "77"], [-37.8189363667,
> 175.2211582333, "25"], [-37.8196676167, 175.2209947333, "26B"], [-37.8194113, 175.2211991, "26"], [-37.81883205, 175.2209747, "27"],
> [-37.8186925833, 175.2207728833, "29"], [-37.8199931833,
> 175.2240802167, "2"], [-37.8191759333, 175.2208279333, "30"], [-37.81835395, 175.2196571667, "39"], [-37.8198807333, 175.2235938167,
> "6"], [-37.8194567833, 175.22349015, "7"], [-37.8200507833,
> 175.21933875, "58"], [-37.8197902167, 175.2182408, "59A"], [-37.81991635, 175.21797195, "59B"], [-37.8198223833, 175.2179361833,
> "59C"], [-37.8201049333, 175.2197347167, "60"], [-37.8199380333,
> 175.21836645, "61A"], [-37.82003775, 175.2182443833, "61B"], [-37.8200944167, 175.21803015, "61C"], [-37.8201259667,
> 175.2185610667, "63"], [-37.82026275, 175.2188001167, "65"], [-37.8188917833, 175.2203729333, "34"], [-37.8184921333, 175.2203832,
> "33"], [-37.8190387167, 175.2206181333, "32"], [-37.81968705,
> 175.2224253667, "16"], [-37.81981205, 175.223119, "10"], [-37.8193882833, 175.2229798333, "11"], [-37.8190901167,
> 175.2227829833, "13B"], [-37.8193593, 175.2227247833, "13"], [-37.81993935, 175.2226893333, "14B"], [-37.81842725, 175.2201474167,
> "35"], [-37.8187965833, 175.2200475333, "36"], [-37.8183878167,
> 175.2198735667, "37"], [-37.8188702167, 175.2196982333, "38B"], [-37.82027885, 175.2209890667, "82"], [-37.8199839667, 175.2190668,
> "56"], [-37.8187008333, 175.21973745, "38A"], [-37.8196820167,
> 175.22262455, "14"], [-37.8186528333, 175.2191018, "42"], [-37.8182912167, 175.21915535, "43"], [-37.81870525, 175.21945675,
> "40"], [-37.8195044333, 175.2214081833, "24"], [-37.81857075,
> 175.2205925167, "31"], [-37.8195656167, 175.2181396, "57"], [-37.8198411667, 175.2213911167, "24A"], [-37.8195851667,
> 175.2240869667, "3"], [-37.8192829167, 175.2239720167, "3A"], [-37.8193257, 175.2224725667, "15"], [-37.8197290167, 175.2224129833,
> "16A"], [-37.8196499333, 175.2221262667, "18"], [-37.8196755333,
> 175.2243193333, "1"], [-37.8192091667, 175.22166805, "21"], [-37.81957585, 175.22166585, "22"], [-37.8199106833, 175.2238436,
> "4"], [-37.81953715, 175.22372785, "5A"], [-37.8193377833,
> 175.22378105, "5"], [-37.8189702833, 175.2184597333, "46"], [-37.8185876167, 175.21821495, "47A"], [-37.8185706333,
> 175.2178869167, "47B"], [-37.8191945667, 175.21845965, "48"], [-37.8188482167, 175.2176680833, "49"], [-37.8194043667, 175.21852395,
> "50"], [-37.8196233333, 175.2186248333, "52"], [-37.81920055,
> 175.2179787167, "53"], [-37.8198255, 175.2188011167, "54"], [-37.8205994333, 175.2207248667, "81"], [-37.8193045333,
> 175.2222075667, "17"], [-37.8205621167, 175.2204520167, "79"], [-37.8180799333, 175.2194407, "41A"], [-37.8208301833, 175.2206735833,
> "81A"], [-37.8202558, 175.2206809333, "80"], [-37.81941275,
> 175.21804965, "55"], [-37.8190239, 175.2179808833, "51"], [-37.8187854, 175.2180712167, "47"], [-37.8187476667, 175.2186516333,
> "44"], [-37.8182977, 175.21889655, "45"], [-37.81831675,
> 175.2194069833, "41"], [-37.8192735167, 175.2219502167, "19"], [-37.8196219167, 175.22189825, "20"], [-37.81962665, 175.2216432667,
> "22A"], [-37.8192782833, 175.2209942, "28"], [-37.8208129833,
> 175.2209176833, "83A"], [-37.8206351167, 175.2209705667, "83"], [-37.8203109333, 175.2212402667, "84"], [-37.81909575, 175.22139795,
> "23"], [-37.8197787167, 175.2228814, "12"], [-37.8195628333,
> 175.21791605, "57A"], [-37.8198373833, 175.2233606833, "8"], [-37.8194342167, 175.22322975, "9"] ];
> 
> 
> var tiles =
> L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {  
> maxZoom: 18,   attribution: '&copy; <a
> href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>
> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ' }),
>     latlng = L.latLng(-37.82, 175.24);
> 
> var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 13, layers: [tiles]});
> 
> 
> var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
> 
> for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {   var a =
> addressPoints[i];   var title = a[2];   var marker = L.marker(new
> L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {title: title});   marker.bindPopup(title);  
> markers.addLayer(marker); }
> 
> markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
>     console.log('cluster with ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length + ' markers in it'); });
> 
> markers.on('click', function (a) {   
>       //how to get the popup content here?
>        console.log(a.layer);
>      });
> 
> map.addLayer(markers);      
> 
> map.on('popupopen', function(e) {   var popupContent = e;   //how to
> get the popup content here?   console.log(e);    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `getPopup` method inherited from `L.Layer`:

```
var popup = e.layer.getPopup();
```

When you have the popup you can use the `getContent` method of `L.Popup`:

```
var content = popup.getContent();
```

Reference:

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#layer-getpopup

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#popup-getcontent

Comment: brilliant.would it have been possible to find that method from the layer object without the api doc?

Comment: Yes, if you would have inspected it in your browser's developer tools you could have followed it's prototype chain.

Answer (score 14):

To get the content of the popup of a marker in Leaflet, use the following code.

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, lon],{title: "Title" }  ).addTo(mymap);
marker.bindPopup("This is popup content");
marker.on('click', onClick);

function onClick(e) {
   var popup = e.target.getPopup();
   var content = popup.getContent();

   console.log(content);
}
```

Comment: I am changing page in my ionic app after a click on the popup and when I again get back from the navigated page the click event is not working. any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to output the value of the function and store it in a variable ?